# What is principal subspace in probabilistic PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, latent-variable, eigenvalues

if $X$ is observed data matrix and $Y$ is latent variable then

$$X=WY+\mu+\epsilon$$

Where $\mu$ is the mean of observed data, and $\epsilon$ is the Gaussian error/noise in data, and $W$ is called principal subspace.

My question is when normal PCA is used we would get a set of orthonormal eigenvectors $E$ for which following is true

$$Y=EX$$

But in PPCA, $W$ is neither orthonormal nor eigenvectors. So how can I get principal components from $W$?

Following my instinct, I searched for [ppca](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ppca.html?searchHighlight=ppca#btp_idz-3) in MATLAB, where I came across this line:

*At convergence, the columns of W spans the subspace, but they are not orthonormal. ppca obtains the orthonormal coefficients, coeff, for the components by orthogonalization of W.*

I modified ppca code a little to get the **W**, ran it and after orthogonalization I did get **P** from **W**.

Why this orthogonalization gave eigenvectors, along which most of variance will be seen?

I am assuming, orthogonalization is giving me a set of orthogonal/orthonormal vectors which span principal subspace, but why this orthogonalized resultant matrix is equal to eigenmatrix(I know that eigenmatrix in pca also orthonormal)? Can I assume principal subspace is spanned only by a unique set of orthonormal vectors? In that case both result will coincide always.

Comment: Just to clear my confusion, I checked exactly where the W is calculated, and assigned it to a new output parameter called prin_sub. I know ppca returns W in S.W, but just to be absolutely clear I redundantly did that. 
and in the document an example was given using data 'hald',
I used their code: P=orth(S.W) 
also @amoeba I deleted my other questions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is an excellent question.

Probabilistic PCA (PPCA) is the following latent variable model
\begin{align}
\mathbf z &\sim \mathcal N(\mathbf 0, \mathbf I) \\
\mathbf x &\sim \mathcal N(\mathbf W \mathbf z + \boldsymbol \mu, \sigma^2 \mathbf I),
\end{align}
where $\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^p$ is one observation and $\mathbf z\in\mathbb R^q$ is a latent variable vector; usually $q\ll p$. Note that this differs from factor analysis *in only one little detail:* error covariance structure in PPCA is $\sigma^2 \mathbf I$ and in FA it is an arbitrary diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol \Psi$.

[Tipping & Bishop, 1999, Probabilistic Principal Component Analysis](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67218/bishop-ppca-jrss.pdf) prove the following theorem: the maximum likelihood solution for PPCA can be obtained analytically and is given by (Eq. 7): $$\mathbf W_\mathrm{ML} = \mathbf U_q (\boldsymbol \Lambda_q - \sigma_\mathrm{ML}^2 \mathbf I)^{1/2} \mathbf R,$$ where $\mathbf U_q$ is a matrix of $q$ leading principal directions (eigenvectors of the covariance matrix), $\boldsymbol \Lambda_q$ is the diagonal matrix of corresponding eigenvalues, $\sigma_\mathrm{ML}^2$ is also given by an explicit formula, and $\mathbf R$ is an arbitrary $q\times q$ rotation matrix (corresponding to rotations in the latent space).

The `ppca()` function implements expectation-maximization algorithm to fit the model, but we know that it must converge to the $\mathbf W_\mathrm{ML}$ as given above.

**Your question is: how to get $\mathbf U_q$ if you know $\mathbf W_\mathrm{ML}$.**

The answer is that you can simply use singular value decomposition of $\mathbf W_\mathrm{ML}$. The formula above is already of the form orthogonal matrix times diagonal matrix times orthogonal matrix, so it gives the SVD, and as it is unique, you will get $\mathbf U_q$ as left singular vectors of $\mathbf W_\mathrm{ML}$.

That is exactly what Matlab's `ppca()` function is doing in line 305:

```
% Orthogonalize W to the standard PCA subspace
[coeff,~] = svd(W,'econ');
```

---

> Can I assume principal subspace is spanned only by a unique set of orthonormal vectors?

No!  There is an infinite number of orthogonal bases spanning the same principal subspace. If you apply some arbitrary orthogonalization process to $\mathbf W_\mathrm{ML}$ you are not guaranteed to obtain $\mathbf U_q$. But if you use SVD or something equivalent, then it will work.